# Scrapy: Modify rules for scraping web page

Tags: javascript, python, regex, scrapy

I've started to use scrapy for a project of mine to scrape data off a tennis website. [Here](http://www.tennisinsight.com/player_activity.php?player_id=1) is an example page that I want to scrape data off. As you can see, I want to scrape data for a tennis player. I need to recursively go through the entire page and gather 'Match Stats' (Theres a link titled 'Match Stats' next to every match) for a player's matches. I've already written code to parse data from the opened match stats popup. All I need to do now is open these match stats pages through the initial spider.

In all the examples I've read up on, we can write rules to navigate scrapy to the different urls that need scraping. In my case, I just want to write a rule to the different match stats links. However, if you saw the page I want to scrape, 'Match Stats' links are in the following format: `javascript:makePopup('match_stats_popup.php?matchID=183704502')`. As I've read online (I might be wrong!), scrapy can't deal with javascript and hence cant 'click' on that link. However, since the links are javascript popups, its possible to add the `match_stats_popup.php?matchID=183704502` part of the link to the main url to get a standard html page:

```
http://www.tennisinsight.com/match_stats_popup.php?matchID=183704502
```

I am hoping I could modify the rules before scraping. In summary, I just want to find the links that are of the type: `javascript:makePopup('match_stats_popup.php?matchID=183704502`, and modify them so that they are now of the type `http://www.tennisinsight.com/match_stats_popup.php?matchID=183704502`

This is what I've written in the rules so far, which doesnt open any pages:

```
rules = (
    Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow='/match_stats_popup.php?matchID=\d+'),
        'parse_match', follow=True,
    ),
)
```

`parse_match` is the method which parses data from the opened match stats popup.

Hope my problem is clear enough!

Comment: When I click on your link, I only see one 'Match Stats' to click on.

Comment: Hi! http://www.tennisinsight.com/player_activity.php?player_id=1
Thats the main link :) There is a history of matches for the player, and each match has a corresponding MatchStats link, which opens a pop-up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `BaseSgmlLinkExtractor` or `SgmlLinkExtractor` you can specify both the tag(s) from which to extract and `process_value` function used for extracting the link. There is [nice example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#basesgmllinkextractor) in the official documentation. Here is the code for your example:

```
class GetStatsSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'GetStats'
    allowed_domains = ['tennisinsight.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.tennisinsight.com/player_activity.php?player_id=1']

    def getPopLink(value):
        m = re.search("javascript:makePopup\('(.+?)'\)", value)
        if m:
            return m.group(1)

    rules = (
            Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=r"match_stats_popup.php\?matchID=\d+",
                restrict_xpaths='//td[@class="matchStyle"]',
                tags='a', attrs='href', process_value=getPopLink), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
            )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        i = TennisItem()
        i['url_stats'] = response.url
        return i
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Here's the url: http://www.tennisinsight.com/player_activity.php?player_id=1
It's got a list of matches played with a match stats link. Based on the link you provided (thanks!), would the code look something like this:

Comment: m = re.search("javascript:makePopup('match_stats_popup.php?matchID=\d+')", value)
What does m.group[1] refer to in the example? :)